# Module declaration with inner classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For example, I have file `list.rb`

```
module List
 class Base
 #...
 end
end
```

So in outer files this class would be accessible as `List::Base`.

Let's say I create another file `list_base_extenstion.rb`

I can do this:

```
module List
 class BaseExtension < Base
 #...
 end
end
```

Or

```
class BaseExtension < List::Base
end
```

Is this equal?

Or then BaseExtension will not be considered the part of module, but inherit directly from `List::Base`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not equal. If you use

```
module List
  class BaseExtension < Base
  end
end
```

you define a class called `List::BaseExtension` that inherits from `List::Base`. Instead, with

```
class BaseExtension < List::Base
end
```

you define a class called `BaseExtension` that inherits from `List::Base`. The class will be defined outside the scope of `List`.